# MongoDB poor write performance on large collections with 50.000.000 documents plus

Tags: mongodb

I have got a MongoDB which store product data for **204.639.403** items, those data has already spitted up, by the item's country, into **four logical** databases running on the same physical machine in the same MongoDB process.

Here is a list with the number of documents per logical database:

- CoUk: **56.719.977**
- De: **61.216.165**
- Fr: **52.280.460**
- It: **34.422.801**

My problem is that the database write performance is getting worser, especially writes to the largest of the four databases (De) has become really bad, according to `iotop` the mongod process uses **99%** of the IO time with less than 3MB writes and 1.5MB reads per second. This leads to long locking databases, **100%+** lock become normally according to `mongostat` - even if all processes writing and reading to the other country databases has been stopped. The current slave reaches a LOAD up to 6, the replica set master has a load of 2-3 at the same time, therefore it leads to a replication lag, too.

Each databases has the same data and index structure, I am using the largest database (De) for further examples only.

This is a random item taken from the database, just as example, the structure is optimized to gather all important data with a single read:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("533b675dba0e381ecf4daa86"),
    "ProductId" : "XGW1-E002F-DW",
    "Title" : "Sample item",
    "OfferNew" : {
        "Count" : 7,
        "LowestPrice" : 2631,
        "OfferCondition" : "NEW"
    },
    "Country" : "de",
    "ImageUrl" : "http://….jpg",
    "OfferHistoryNew" : [ 
        … 
        {
            "Date" : ISODate("2014-06-01T23:22:10.940+02:00"),
            "Value" : {
                "Count" : 10,
                "LowestPrice" : 2171,
                "OfferCondition" : "NEW"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Processed" : ISODate("2014-06-09T23:22:10.940+02:00"),
    "Eans" : [ 
        "9781241461959"
    ],
    "OfferUsed" : {
        "Count" : 1,
        "LowestPrice" : 5660,
        "OfferCondition" : "USED"
    },
    "Categories" : [ 
        NumberLong(186606), 
        NumberLong(541686), 
        NumberLong(288100), 
        NumberLong(143), 
        NumberLong(15777241)
    ]
}
```

Typical querys are form simple one like by the ProductId or an EAN only to refinements by the category and sorted by its A rank or refinements by the category and an A rank range (1 up to 10.000 for example) and sorted by the B rank… .

This are the stats from the largest db:

```
{
    "ns" : "De.Item",
    "count" : 61216165,
    "size" : 43915150656,
    "avgObjSize" : 717,
    "storageSize" : 45795192544,
    "numExtents" : 42,
    "nindexes" : 6,
    "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 0,
    "userFlags" : 1,
    "totalIndexSize" : 41356824320,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 2544027808,
        "RankA_1" : 1718096464,
        "Categories_1_RankA_1_RankB_-1" : 16383534832,
        "Eans_1" : 2846073776,
        "Categories_1_RankA_-1" : 15115290064,
        "ProductId_1" : 2749801376
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

It is mentionable that the index size is **nearly half of the storage size**.

Each country DB **has to handle 3-5 million updates/inserts per day**, my target is to perform the write operations in less than five hours during the night.

Currently it's a replica set with two servers, each has 32GB RAM and a RAID1 with 2TB HDDs. Simple optimizations like the deadlock scheduler and noatime has already been made.

I have worked out some optimizations strategies:

- Reducing the number indexes:
- - the default _id could use the ProductId instead of the default MongoId which would save 6-7% per DB per total nixes size.
- - Trying to remove the Categories_1_RankA_-1 index maybe the BrowseNodes_1_RankA_1_RankB_-1 index could handle the query, too. Does sorting still performs well when not the complete index is used? Another way would be storing the index matching Categories_1_RankA_1_RankB_-1 in another collection which refers to the main collection.
- Reducing the amount of raw data by using smaller keys, instead of 'Categories', 'Eans', 'OfferHistoryNew'… I could use 'a', 'b', 'c'… this should be easy since I used http://mongojack.org/ but I don't now how worthwhile it will be.
- Replacing the RAID1 with a RAID0, could be easily tested by taken the slave down, reinstalling and reading it to the replica set… .
- Testing stronger Hardware SSDs and more memory which should handle the reads and writes faster.
- Use MongoDB's shading capabilities:
- - I read that each shard has to hold the whole database index?
- - I have concerns that the query structure might not fit into a sharing environment well. Using the product id as shard key seems to fit not all query types and sharding by the category is complicated, too. A single item can be listed in multiple main and sub categories … . My concerns could be wrong, I never used it in a production environment.

But there should be other optimization strategies, too did not comes to my mind I would like to hear about!
Which optimization strategy sound most promising or is a mixture of several optimizations is needed here?

Comment: For historical reasons, it is worth noting that [this Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/mongodb/comments/2bas22/mongodb_poor_write_performance_on_large/) contains discussion related to this question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most likely you are running into issues due to record growth, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-performance/#document-growth.

Mongo prefers records of fixed (or at least bounded) size. Increasing the record size beyond the pre-allocated storage will cause the document to be moved to another location on disk, multiplying your I/O with each write. Consider pre-allocating "enough" space for your average document on insert, if your document sizes are relatively homogenous. Otherwise consider splitting rapidly growing nested arrays into a separate collection, thereby replacing updates with inserts. Also check your fragmentation and consider compacting your databases from time to time, so that you have a higher density of documents per block which will cut down on hard page faults.

Comment: The padding factor was 1 (no padding), I'm trying now the usePowerOf2Sizes flag:
```
db.runCommand( {collMod: "Item", usePowerOf2Sizes : true })
```

Comment: The padding has a great effect to the writes, but besides the padding the indexes have been optimized. Both optimizations had a great impact to the write performance!

- With optimized indexes: 4:47 for 2.5 Million updates
- With optimized indexed and padding: 1:15 for 1.5 Million updates
- Without any optimizations: 9:17 for 1.2 Million updates

The next steps I gonna optimize are the IOPS, currently I'm testing a RAID0 the next step will be moving the journal to another HDD.

Comment: How exactly did you optimize your indexes?

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using a database with better throughput that supports documents? I've heard success stories with [TokuMX](http://www.tokutek.com/products/tokumx-for-mongodb/). And [FoundationDB](https://foundationdb.com/key-value-store/white-papers/the-layer-concept) (where I'm an engineer) has very good performance with high-concurrent write loads and large documents. Happy to answer further questions about FoundationDB.

Comment: Thanks, never heard about TokuMX but I give it a try.
About FoundationDB seeems to be key/value store, but I need a dbms with nested documents and multiple indexing… this seems to not fit my needs.

Comment: FDB is key/value at its base, but supports more features (like nested documents and multiple indexing) through layers. Obviously I'm biased to think that its the best choice so I won't harp on it more here :)