# Write performance is decreased when collection is increased

Tags: mongodb, performance

My problem : MongoDB poor write performance on large collection

Begin: peformance is 70,000 doc/sec (empty collection)
For a while, my collection is getting larger.
End: performance is  < 10,000 doc/sec (0.4 billion docs in collection)

There are my records below:
[Write Performance with Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9r50.png) 
[Write Performance with Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pa84.png)

And then, I make a new collection in the same database, 
I write two collection at the same time.
The Large collection (ns: "rf1.case1") performance is still slow, 
but New collection (ns: "rf1.case2") performance is pretty fast.

I have already read [MongoDB poor write performance on large collections with 50.000.000 documents plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868171/mongodb-poor-write-performance-on-large-collections-with-50-000-000-documents-pl) , but I still no idea !

Is my configuration wrong?

---

3 Servers are the same Hardware Specfication:

- CPU: 8 core
- Memory: 32GB
- Disk: 2TB HDD (7200rpm)

My Scenario:

```
    There are 3 shards(Replica Set):
    Server1 : primary(sh01) + secondary(sh03) + arbiter(sh02) + configsvr + mongos
    Server2 : primary(sh02) + secondary(sh01) + arbiter(sh03) + configsvr + mongos
    Server3 : primary(sh03) + secondary(sh02) + arbiter(sh01) + configsvr + mongos
```

Mongod sample:

```
    /usr/local/mongodb/bin/mongod --quiet --port 20001 --dbpath $s1 --logpath $s1/s1.log --replSet sh01 --shardsvr --directoryperdb --fork --storageEngine wiredTiger --wiredTigerCollectionBlockCompressor snappy --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 8
```

Two Collection:

```
(chunksize = 64MB) 
            rf1.case1
                    shard key: { "_id" : "hashed" }
                    chunks:
                            host1   385
                            host2   401
                            host3   367
                    too many chunks to print, use verbose if you want to force print
            rf1.case2
                    shard key: { "_id" : "hashed" }
                    chunks:
                            host1   11
                            host2   10
                            host3   10
```

Comment: If you restart your cluster, does it makes any difference in write performance? I believe, it's your IO (disk).  What your MongoDB version and storage engine? WiredTiger?

Comment: thx Saleem your reply. I restart my all servers and cluster, it's still no difference.  (1)MongoDB Version: 3.0.9  (2)Mongod Engine: WiredTiger.